# How to have single sign-in form for two devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have two devise models.

```
devise_for :contractors
devise_for :customers
```

To make it easier for the users and also cleaner on the frontend. I wish one sign in form in my navbar through both `customers` and `contractors` can sign in.

So, i am wondering, how to do that ? Should I have override devise's `session controller`? If so how. I could have sign in for one devise model through how is is mentioned here - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app . But over there only its only accepts one `resource` and `resource name`. Whereas in this case there two models.

what is the right away to solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a particularly good reason, I would suggest that you don't have 2 completely separate models for the two types of users. You will probably end up duplicating a lot of functionality and encountering a lot of odd problems (like this one). I would having one `User` model and having a flag to say which kind of user they are. If they have to have two different types of profile because they have a lot of different relevant fields then I'd either use `serialize` and serialize a hash of key/value pairs or have `user belongs_to :profile` and have `ContractorProfile` and `CustomerProfile`. The profile relationship would then be polymorphic and then point to either of these types.

You don't want to bifurcate into two different types of user when so much of the functionality between them will just be duplicated. If they have to operate somewhat differently then fair enough, but do the splitting further down the line.

Comment: Well except for the name they dont have any similar fields. Having one table/model will just end up in numerous empty fields once a user gets created of a certain type. Thats why I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: What about splitting the empty fields out into separate profile objects as I suggest? Then the user-type specific fields can go in separate objects but they can each use the same basic model for authentication etc.

Comment: split into , where? Sorry i am new to rails and web application dev.

Comment: OK sure no problem. To be honest if you are new to this stuff then I would probably actually suggest just going with having a load of empty columns. It's not ideal but not fundamentally wrong in any way. It will save you from a lot of crap (like having to do authentication, permissions, etc twice) and it wouldn't make it any harder for you to improve later. Having 2 different auth etc. methods would be hard and non-standard and unpleasant, and would be hard to undo.

Comment: hmm, alright. I will still dig the internet for what you mentioned and see if i can find a cleaner way :P. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually i found an article here - http://jessepollak.me/2012/07/10/single-sign-in-for-multiple-user-types-in-devise/ and seems to work fine. but thanks for your answer, i think i understand a little why you say having one table will help in future.